# Power BI execute stored procedure on click event of a button

Tags: button, stored-procedures, powerbi

I have a Stored procedure in SQL without any parameter, I only need to have a button in Power BI when the user clicks on this button the stored procedure executes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Paginated Report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi).  They support running stored procedures, and rendering the results too.

Comment: Thanks, but Report Builder is required for Paginated Reports, then I prefer alternative solutions.

Comment: Power apps is the alternative.